# why is my code saying' Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'calculator' has already been declared' in the console?

Tags: javascript

I tried making a calculator, but checking it at this stage, it's displaying some syntax error.

Please I need help. How can I correct this? There is a class of calculator there and I represented it with the 'new' word. This is vanilla JavaScript. Tried calling the function, but it kept on giving me the error in my console. Please could someone help me?

```js
class calculator {
  constructor(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement) {
    this.perviousOperandTextElement = previousOperandTextElement
    this.currentOperandTextElement = currentOperandTextElement
    this.clear()
  }
    
  clear() {
    this.currentOperand = ''
    this.previousOperand = ''
    this.operation = undefined
  }
    
  delete() {
  }

  appendNumber(number) {
    this.currentOperand = number
  }
    
  chooseOperation(operation) {   
  }
    
  compute() {
  }

  updateDisplay() {
    this.currentOperandTextElement.innerText = this.currentOperand;
  }
}
    
const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]')
const operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operation]')
const equalsButton = document.querySelector('[data-equals]')
const deleteButton = document.querySelector('[data-delete]')
const allclearButton = document.querySelector('[data-all-clear]')
const previousOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-previous-operand]')
const currentOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-current-operand]')
        
const calculator = new calculator(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement)

numberButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText)
    calculator.updateDisplay()
  })
})
```

Comment: You have a class called `calculator` and a variable called `calculator`.  Rename one of them.

Comment: UpperCase first letter of the class name Calculator

Answer (score 0):

Identifier 'calculator' has already been declared' means you've used name 'calculator' twice, in your code - class is named 'calculator' and constant for calculator object is also 'calculator'.

Change class name to 'Calculator':

```
class Calculator {
  constructor(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement) {
    this.perviousOperandTextElement = previousOperandTextElement
    this.currentOperandTextElement = currentOperandTextElement
    this.clear()
  }

  clear() {
    this.currentOperand = ''
    this.previousOperand = ''
    his.operation = undefined
  }

  delete() {

  }

  appendNumber(number) {
   this.currentOperand = number
  }

  chooseOperation(operation) {

  }

  compute() {

  }

  updateDisplay() {
    this.currentOperandTextElement.innerText = this.currentOperand;
  }
}



const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]')
const operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operation]')
const equalsButton = document.querySelector('[data-equals]')
const deleteButton = document.querySelector('[data-delete]')
const allclearButton = document.querySelector('[data-all-clear]')
const previousOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-previous-operand]')
const currentOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-current-operand]')
    
// error was here
const calculator = new Calculator(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement)



numberButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText)
    calculator.updateDisplay()
  })
})
```

P.S. always name your classes with upper case first letter, that is the convention